# Why is this polynomial not a vector space?

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

Consider the following subsets of the vector space of polynomials of degree $4$ or less.

a) The set of polynomials in $P_4$ that satisfy $p(0) = 1$ and $p(1) = 2$

b) The set of polynomials in $P_4$ that satisfy $p(1) = 1$ and $p'(1) = 2$

Are these two sets of polynomials subspaces of $P_4$? Why or why not?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Begin with the vector space axioms. Are they satisfied? Check them one-by-one; it is tedious but not so hard.

Comment: What is the definition of a subspace? Which part of the definition is easiest to find a counter example for?

Comment: Nobody's going to point out the terrible title? The correct answer to the title is "because 0 is the only polynomial which 'is' a vector space."

Comment: @Cass Well, $0$ is different than $\{0\}$, so I wouldn't make that statement either.  (Of course you know this already.)

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2):

All vector spaces have an additive identity. The additive identity with respect to the addition of polynomials is the $0$ polynomial. If a set of polynomials does not contain $0$, it is not a vector space.

Answer (score 0):

For part a. consider any polynomial $p$ where $p(0) = 1$.  Any scalar $a \in \mathbb{R}$ will satisfy $ap(0) = a\cdot 1 = a$, therefore polynomials of the first type are not closed under scalar multiplication.

Actually, the same exact principle can be applied for the second part as well.

Answer (score 0):

$a)$ is not a subspace because if $p, q \in A \to  r = p + q \notin A$ since $r(0) = p(0)+q(0) = 1+1 = 2 \neq 1$. The same happens to $b)$ as closure property fails...